# C# myListView.Items[0].Selected -- "Selected" isn't defined?

Tags: c#, listview

So this one has been driving me a bit batty...

I have a ListView objected which I've created by dragging and dropping from the toolbox onto the graphic window designer area. I've given it a name like "myListView" in the properties panel, and it has worked as expected up until this point (data is being displayed properly, I can graphically select an item and it highlights, etc.)

So today, I am trying to programatically select one of the items in myListView, with the following line of code:

```
myListView.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

However, this is giving me a compilation error, specifically that "Selected" is undefined in the object.

Essentially, there is no "Selected" property in myListview.Items[] and I can't figure out why or how to fix it. In fact, there don't appear to be "any" properties at all. Everything I've found on-line seems to confirm that I'm doing this correctly, but, like Alderan, it's just not there. :)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to what you're doing wrong. ListViewItems definitely have a `Selected` property, as I've just tried it myself. Could you show us more of your code?

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms? (I suspect you are using WPF).

Comment: @Edward has a good question. The above works fine in WinForms but in WPF I think you're going to get issues as `myListView.Items[0]` is going to return you the object stored in the list view and `.Selected` is trying to access a property on that object

Comment: You guys nailed it.  That's exactly what was happening.  I am working in WPF.  I'm pretty new to this, having migrated over from the MacOS platform just a few days ago. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WPF, ListView.Items is a collection of objects, hence you don't see any properties. To select the first item in a WPF ListView, you can do this:

```
myListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: That's exactly what was happening.  I managed to stumble on the answer quite by accident, but by the time I came back here to add it I saw you guys had already figured it out.  A+ and extra credit for promptness! lol